# ¿Como puedo eliminar el ultimo caracter ANTES de un caracter determinado? Java

Tags: java, string

mi consulta es la siguiente:
<**En una terminal de teletipo existe un carácter de retroceso que permite cancelar el último carácter.
Por ejemplo: si el carácter de retroceso es /, entonces la línea abc/d//e será interpretada como ae. Existe también un carácter anulador que elimina todos los caracteres ingresados hasta el momento, suponga que ese carácter es &.**>

Todo esto es leyendolo de un archivo previamente cargado con alguna linea.
Lo que hice hasta ahora fue leer la linea y guardarla en un String, luego pase el String a un vector de Char, y posteriormente pase cada caracter a un ArrayList, para poder eliminar tanto el caracter '/' como el anterior, el problema es que no se puede iterar una lista y modificarla al mismo tiempo, queria saber si hay alguna manera no tan engorrosa de complicarla creando otra lista guardando los indices de las ocurrencias y su anterior.

```
public class TercerEjercicio {
    private static String linea = null;

    public static void leerArchivo(String archivoin) {
        try {
            BufferedReader leer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(archivoin));
            String aux= null;
            while((aux = leer.readLine()) != null) {

                linea = aux;
            }
            System.out.println("el contenido del archivo es: "+linea);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }

    public static void crearArchivo(String archivoOut) {
        try {
            File file=new File(archivoOut);
            file.createNewFile();
            System.out.println("Archivo creado");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }


    public static void escribirArchivo(String archivoOut) {
        String lineaOut=null;

        try {
            BufferedWriter escribir= new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(archivoOut));

            lineaOut = analizarLinea(linea);

            escribir.write(lineaOut);
            escribir.close();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }

    }

    private static String analizarLinea(String linea) {
        String out= null;
        char[] vector = linea.toCharArray();

// aqui es donde se debe hacer la logica del problema//

        return out;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes obtener el valor de vuelta de este método y utilizarlo como gustes:

```
private static String analizarLinea(String linea) {
    String out = "";
    char[] vector = linea.toCharArray();
    //El metodo devuelve un String
    System.out.println(eliminarCaracter(linea, 0));
    return out;
}

private static String eliminarCaracter(String linea, int index){
    //Ciclo que se ejecuta mientras el texto contenga '/' y no se rebase tamaño del texto
    while(index < linea.length() - 1 && linea.contains("/")){

        //Toma el caracter siguiente
        String caracterPosterior = String.valueOf(linea.toCharArray()[index + 1]);

        if(caracterPosterior.equals("/")){
            //Si es igual a '/' va a tomar esos dos caracteres
            String remove = linea.substring(index, index + 2);

            //Y los elimina
            linea = linea.replaceFirst(remove, "");

            //Se devuelve al caracter anterior para comprobar si este no tiene otro '/' delante
            index--;
        } else {
            //Si no tiene un '/' delante prosigue con el ciclo
            index++;
        }
    }

    if(String.valueOf(linea.toCharArray()[0]).equals("/")){
        //Sentencia para detectar si el primer caracter es '/'
        linea = linea.replaceFirst("/", "");
    }
    return linea;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías jugar con los métodos `lastIndexOf`, `indexOf` y `substring` que tiene el tipo de dato `String` y no tener que crear arreglos de `char` para tener un código más corto y entendible sin tanto loop, a cambio de ser un poquito menos eficiente en el uso de recursos. Algo así:

```
private static String analizarLinea(String linea) {
    int ultimoAnulador = linea.lastIndexOf('&'); //Buscar el índice del último anulador
    String nuevaLinea = (ultimoAnulador == -1) ? linea : linea.substring(ultimoAnulador + 1); //Recortar la linea
    String lineaTemporal; //Temporal para comparar
    do {
        lineaTemporal = nuevaLinea; //Iguala a la linea sin recortar
        nuevaLinea = procesarRetroceso(nuevaLinea); //Recortar la linea según la primera aparicion del retroceso
    } while(!lineaTemporal.equals(nuevaLinea)); //Repetir si hubo un recorte de linea

    return nuevaLinea; //Devuelve la linea analizada
}

public static String procesarRetroceso(String linea) {
    int primerRetroceso = linea.indexOf('/'); //Busca la primera aparición del retroceso
    switch(primerRetroceso) {
        case -1: //No encontró un retroceso
            return linea; //Devuelve la linea sin recortar
        case 0: //El primer caracter es un retroceso
            return linea.substring(1); //Quita el primer caracter y devuelve el resto de la linea
        default:
            return linea.substring(0, primerRetroceso - 1) + linea.substring(primerRetroceso + 1); //Quita el primer caracter de retroceso y el caracter anterior a éste y une los dos segmentos resultantes
    }
}
```

Sería cuestión de llamar al método `analizarLinea` para obtener la línea modificada.

Si lo quieres eficiente lo mejor sería trabajar con un arreglo de `char` y recorrerlo iterativamente pero el código (como dijiste) se hace un poco engorroso.